# Is it OK to evaluate improper integrals this way?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Today in class we learned that when you have an improper integral like this one:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {f(x)} \: dx$$

you must split it before you do the limits (like so):

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^n {f(x)} \: dx + \lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{n}^a {f(x)} \: dx$$

I asked if this would work:

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a {f(x)} \: dx$$

And my teacher said it wouldn't work, but he wouldn't explain why. Why wouldn't that work? An example of a function that doesn't work would be especially nice.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831178/intuitively-why-does-int-infty-infty-sinxdx-diverge

Comment: I tried the same thing, and it didn't work in a case. That's what convinced me I couldn't do this

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that limiting to both infinities at the same time can overlook divergence.

However, the value: $\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x)\,dx$ (if it exists) is important enough to have a name: the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

So why can't you just do the limit like this? Consider $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$

Notice that $\int_0^\infty x\,dx$ diverges to $\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0 x\,dx$ diverges to $-\infty$. So we get (from either side) that our integral diverges.

However, $\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a x\,dx = \lim\limits_{a \to\infty} a^2/2 - (-a)^2/2 = \lim\limits_{a \to \infty} 0 = 0$.

So the principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$ is zero while the integral itself diverges.

In general, **IF** an improper integral converges, you can be very sloppy and get the right answer. On the other hand, if it actually diverges, sloppiness can miss this!

As I tell my students: You must approach **ONE** side of **EACH** bad spot by itself. Then put your answer together.

*Addendum:* Suppose $\int_{-\infty}^c f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_c^\infty f(x)\,dx$ exist.

Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \lim\limits_{a \to -\infty} \int_a^c f(x)\,dx + \lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \int_c^b f(x)\,dx = \lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \int_{-b}^c f(x)\,dx + \lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \int_c^b f(x)\,dx$

Now because those two limits exist, we can combine them. So we get...

$=\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \int_{-b}^c f(x)\,dx + \int_c^b f(x)\,dx 
=\lim\limits_{b \to \infty} \int_{-b}^b f(x)\,dx$

...which is the principal value. So the improper integral and principal value match when the integral actually converges.

Comment: And as further evidence that using $\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a x\,dx$ is wrong, consider that $\lim\limits_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^{a+1} x\,dx$ obviously diverges, but there's no reason why we couldn't just as well use that to represent $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dx$. Being more symmetrical doesn't make the first one more right ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Exactly. That's what I tried explain in my answer.

Answer (score 16):

(There is already a good answer, but I thought I'd add something.)

We say that a limit exists, if no matter how we approach it approaches the same. For example
$$-1 = \lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{|x|}{x}\neq\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{|x|}{x} = 1 $$
and hence the limit $\lim_{x\to0}|x|/x$ does not exist. In a similar way, we have to consider any way the interval of integration $[a,b]$ grows, where $a\to-\infty$ and $b\to\infty$.

Consider for example
\begin{align}
&\int_{-n}^{2n} x\,\mathrm{d}x =\frac{3}{2}n^2 &\text{and }\quad &\int_{-n}^n x\,\mathrm{d}x
 = 0.\end{align}
As $n$ approaches $\infty$ the interval is $[-\infty,\infty]$ for both integrals, but approaching in different ways. In this example we have that the first integral goes to infinity, however the second integral seems to converge? As I said, a limit has to be the same no matter how we approach it, so the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,\mathrm{d}x$$
actually diverges (which it does not using "your" method). I hope this helps you see why it is important to consider the end-points of the interval independently.

Answer (score 2):

The only case in which you can not define the integral that way is when $f$ is not integrable. In terms of the Lebesgue integral you can check this for positive functions.

Wikipedia mentions
$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}  \;1 \; \; x > 0 \\ -1 \;\;x < 0 \end{array} \right. .$$

You can check that this has $0$ at each term in the sequence $\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow \infty} \int\limits_{-a}^a f(x) dx$, but is clearly not integrable by the definition of the Riemann integral or the Lebesgue integral.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a " discontinuity " at the point "n" , then combining the two integrals ,  will not (may not) give the correct result.