# Why does not $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,\mathrm{d}x$ converge?

Tags: improper-integrals

It seems natural that it should converge, because for any $A\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\int_{-A}^A x\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-A}^0 x\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^A x\,\mathrm{d}x=\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_{-A}^0+\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^A=-\frac{(-A)^2}{2}+\frac{A^2}{2}=0.$$

So the integral is zero for every such value $A$, yet it doesn't converge, according to wolfram alpha. How come?

Comment: See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070992/is-it-ok-to-evaluate-improper-integrals-this-way/1071041#1071041) on this question, or the other answers.

Comment: It's desirable that $\int_{-a}^b f(x)\,dx$ be close to the limit whenever both $a>0$ and $b>0$ are large.

Comment: As others have pointed out, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdx$ does not converge; however the calculation in the OP is still useful and is called the [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Answer (score 12):

All that is true, but the **definition** of convergence of integrals of this type is

> The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges if for each $a$ the integrals $\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\,dx$ converge.  In this case
>   $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^a f(x)\,dx+\int_a^{\infty}f(x)\,dx
> $$

Since neither $\int_0^\infty x\,dx$ or $\int_{-\infty}^0x\,dx$ converge, the two-sided improper integral does not converge.

Answer (score 3):

- The integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty x~dx$ diverges for the same reason that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n$ also diverges.
- You write that $\displaystyle\int_{-A}^Ax~dx=0$ for all real *A*. True enough! But $\displaystyle\int_{-A}^{A+B}x~dx\neq0$, for $B\neq0$.

$~\quad~$ Now, let $A\to\infty$ in the latter.