# Why the sum of two divergent integrals has to be divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Suppose $f(x)$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{c\}$, where $c$ is a scalar. Consider the integral

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are such that $a<c<b$. All Calculus books I checked define the integral above to be convergent if and only if $\int_a^cf(x)dx$ and $\int_c^bf(x)dx$ are both convergent, in which case we have:

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^cf(x)dx+\int_c^bf(x)dx$$

It is only a definition, but does it make sense? For example, I can certainly have two series $x_t$ and $y_t$ that are both divergent, but their sum is convergent (the most obvious example is the one where $y_t=-x_t$). The same could occur with integrals. For instance, if I try to integrate $1/x$ from $-1$ to $1$ using the Riemann Sum I would get

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx= \int_{-1}^0\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{n}j}\right)+\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}j}\right)\right]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{j=1}^n0=0$$

And therefore, I would conclude this integral is convergent. But the definition tells me otherwise (since $\int_{-1}^0\frac{1}{x}dx$ is divergent). Any thoughts on why it is defined that way?

Comment: In the equality where you substitute the integrals by series, you have changed the order of the terms of two series which are divergent, the first to $-\infty$ and the second to $+\infty$, and that sum can be any number with the appropiate arrangement by Riemann's theorem. Thus, that limit doesn't exist. I think that the problem is you are using an equality that doesn't hold: $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)+\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x).$

Comment: You might be interested in the Cauchy principal value https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: You cannot just use the same $n$ in the limit of the two integrals. They should be independent of each other. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070992/is-it-ok-to-evaluate-improper-integrals-this-way/1071041#1071041) where a similar question is asked.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem you stated is a property of the definite integral. If we go back to the first fundamental theorem of calculus seen [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html), it says that the functions need to be continuous.  If we consider the [proof the theorem](http://www.tutorvista.com/content/math/calculus/definite-integrals/properties-definite-integrals.php) you stated, you can see it uses the first fundamental theorem of calculus.  Thus, the theorem you talk about assumes that f(x) is continuous for [a,b].  For the integral $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{x}dx$$, this is an improper integral so different rules would apply.